# Перенос строки при чтении из XML

Tags: c#, xml, unity3d

Храню все строковые переменные в XML.

Читаю значение следующим образом

```
XElement oneDic;
// получаю значение
...
// Читаю значение
oneDic.FirstAttribute.Value.ToString();
```

Собственно проблема в том, что при чтении из XML символ /n считывается как отдельных два символа и перенос строки не происходит. Если я ту же самую строку вставлю напрямую в моё текстовое поле, всё нормально переносится. Кодировка XML utf-8

Comment: В `\n` используется backslash, если я правильно помню :)

Comment: @Kirill'luridSNK'F. как его поставить? Я редактирую XML через VisualStudio

Comment: В Финдовсе `\r\n` комбинация переноса строки всегда была вроде

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Чтобы записать в атрибут xml перенос строки, нужно использовать сущности (entities):

```
attr="aaa&#xd;&#xa;bbb"
```

Эти сущности соответствуют значениям `\r\n`. Отмечу, что в Windows используются оба символа одновременно.

Также отмечу, что тип свойства `Value` - строка, поэтому вызов метода `ToString` не нужен.

Comment: Спасибо заработало, можно ссылочку на документацию по этим сущностям